# Getting test failure while running gradle test task and custom integrationTest tasks in a multi module project

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I have configured a gradle task for integrationTest like attached source.
Both `test` and `integrationTest` tasks work fine when executing separately but executing together like `./gradlew clean check` or `./gradlew clean test integrationTest` fails `integrationTest` during `compileIntegrationTestGroovy` phase with error `unable to resolve class...`.

Looking at the `build/classes` directory indicates that post `test` task execution deletes all the generated main and test classes.

Is there any way to disable deletion of classes after `test` or other alternatives to solve the issue.

```
sourceSets {
    'integration-test' {
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
        runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.main.output

        java.srcDir(file('src/integration-test/java'))
        groovy.srcDir(file('src/integration-test/groovy'))
        resources.srcDir(file('src/integration-test/resources'))
    }
}

configurations {
    integrationTestImplementation.extendsFrom(testImplementation)
    integrationTestRuntimeOnly.extendsFrom(testRuntimeOnly)
}

task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    description = 'Executes integration tests'
    group = 'verification'

    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.'integration-test'.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.'integration-test'.runtimeClasspath

    beforeTest { descriptor ->
        logger.lifecycle("Running test: ${descriptor}")
    }

    mustRunAfter(test)
}

check.dependsOn(integrationTest)
```

Result of `./gradlew :app-core:clean :app-core:check --dry-run`. app-core is under root project. `:app-core:compileIntegrationTestGroovy` step fails when `:app-core:check` is actually executed.

```
:app-core:clean SKIPPED
:app-core:compileJava SKIPPED
:app-core:compileGroovy SKIPPED
:app-core:processResources SKIPPED
:app-core:classes SKIPPED
:app-core:compileTestJava SKIPPED
:app-core:compileTestGroovy SKIPPED
:app-core:processTestResources SKIPPED
:app-core:testClasses SKIPPED
:app-core:test SKIPPED
:app-core:compileIntegrationTestJava SKIPPED
:app-core:compileIntegrationTestGroovy SKIPPED
:app-core:processIntegrationTestResources SKIPPED
:app-core:integrationTestClasses SKIPPED
:app-core:integrationTest SKIPPED
:app-core:check SKIPPED
```

Comment: The `test` task shouldn't do that, so maybe the `clean` task is not running at in the correct order. This can happen by things like [Gradle issue 2488](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2488). Could you try running `./gradlew clean check --dry-run` and see if the `clean` task shows up first in the list?

Comment: Have added dry-run result to the post. `clean` is at the top and supposedly execute once.